# GREP terms for searching a dash followed by a string of numbers and a paragraph break

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep, regex

I need to find several text-elements that have a structure like

```
 — 12345
```

or

```
 — 123456
```

or

```
 — 1234567
```

in InDesign via GREP - I can't display that in stackoverflow, but each of these terms is followed by a ¶. Could somebody help me finding the right search-term or generally does anybody know some sort of "generator" for those GREP-searches?

Comment: So followed by end of paragraph or end of paragraph character?

Comment: — 1234567¶ would be the correct term

Comment: @Vinny Please do not answer in the comments; see for example https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments

Comment: @Luciano Maybe you're right, but I'm usually reluctant to answer when the lack of information prevents an accurate answer.

Comment: @Vinny Write one based on what's in the question, or don't write it at all. Chances are: either OP comes back to clarify and gets a proper answer later, or doesn't and your comment is enough, in which case the question stays open forever since there's no accepted answer. Comments should be for requesting clarification and commenting, that's all.

Comment: OK comment deleted, whatever...

Comment: @Vinny you're welcome to leave an answer and if the question changed you could always make an edit to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is somewhat unclear but you could do the following in InDesign with GREP:

```
 — 12345
```

try: `^ — \d{5}`

```
 — 123456
```

try: `^ — \d{6}`

```
 — 1234567
```

If you're looking for a range from `12345` to `1234567` try `^ — \d{5,7}`.  Based on what you left in the comment for:

```
— 1234567¶
```

you could use `— \d{5,7}¶` or `— \d{5,7}$`.  If you want to find anything after the dash that is numerical you can also do `— \d+$`.  The usage of `^` indicated beginning of line so if these are in between text omit `^`.

If you wanted to reuse the numbers for any reason just surround the digit with `()` for example:

```
— 12345
```

try: `— (\d{5,7})`

A good reference for GREP in InDesign:

- [Favorite GREP Expressions You Can Use](https://indesignsecrets.com/favorite-grep-expressions-you-can-use.php)
- [FindBetween: A Useful GREP String](https://indesignsecrets.com/findbetween-a-useful-grep-string.php)